# Personalize ListView item in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to personalize ListView Item like in the picture, I want to add 2 button ( 1 and 2 in the picture ) and I want to remove the white space (3 in the picture )

[image]

this is the code of my List view item

```
<li data-icon="false"><a href="index.html">
  <img src="images/bureau.jpg">
  <h2>Avery Walker</h2>
  <p><strong>Re: Ce soir dîner</strong></p>
  <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>50</strong>£</p>
  <p class="ui-li-count"><strong>5</strong></p>
</li>
```

If you have any idea to make it please tell me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS and absolute positioning to place the buttons as you desire. I have assigned a class of myCustomUL to the listview and then within the listitems, I add an absolutely positioned div with a class of cust-btns. The div includes the up and down buttons and the count.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="myCustomUL">
    <li data-icon="false"> 
        <a href="index.html">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80/food/1/" />
            <h2>Avery Walker</h2>
            <p><strong>Re: Ce soir dîner</strong></p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>50</strong>£</p>                     
        </a>
        <div class="cust-btns"> 
            <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-u ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all">Icon only</a>
            <p class="ui-li-count"><strong>5</strong>
            </p> <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all">Icon only</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS. The first rule affects the distance between the text and the buttons on the right, so tweak to your taste. The remaining rules place the buttons.

```
.myCustomUL li > a {
    padding-right: 56px !important;
}
.myCustomUL .cust-btns {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; width: 39px;
    bottom: 0px; right: 0px; left: auto;
}
.myCustomUL .cust-btns a:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.myCustomUL .cust-btns a:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.myCustomUL .cust-btns .ui-li-count {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    left: 4px;
    right: auto;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/RK4mc/1/)**